# How to render a page full of special charachters without escaping every single one

Tags: reactjs, escaping, special-characters

I am learning react and I am trying to create a practice app where I put my notes so I am able to easily access them when I change computers.

I have a long cheatsheet full of code that I would like to display in a page, but I cannot escape every single special charachter and keyword because basically it is full of it.

Hope this makes sense, let me know if any clarification is needed. Any advice on how to get around this would be so so appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would need more clarification about your cheatsheet content, but if it's a richtext cheatsheet you could try using dangerouslySetInnerHtml

You could try to put everything inside there and i think it should render corretcly.

```
function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={myContent} />;
}
```

Comment: This is it:

https://pastebin.com/ZkuuyHPN

After googling I think what I need is a scape function? I think like this?

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/Javascript+Escape+Html+String

If you know of a better way please let me know because I am not entirely sure I can make that work still.

Also thank you for taking the time to reply to me :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library named [remarkable](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable) for that matter.

Here is a simple example taken from [React official documentation](https://reactjs.org/).

```
class MarkdownEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.md = new Remarkable();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = { value: 'Hello, **world**!' };
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }

  getRawMarkup() {
    return { __html: this.md.render(this.state.value) };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="MarkdownEditor">
        <h3>Input</h3>
        <label htmlFor="markdown-content">
          Enter some markdown
        </label>
        <textarea
          id="markdown-content"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          defaultValue={this.state.value}
        />
        <h3>Output</h3>
        <div
          className="content"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.getRawMarkup()}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally React escapes Text automatically. If you only want to display the Text you don't need to escape anything, e.g. consider this code and type any special chars in the input box:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
export const EscapeText = (props)=>{
    const [ value, setValue ] = useState('');
    return (<>
        <input
            value={ value }
            onChange={ function(event){
                setValue( event.target.value );
            }}
        />
        { value }
    </>);
};
```

In case you want to display formatted HTML, you can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) *(as other answers suggested)*, but generally this should be avoided if possible, because it is *dangerous*.

Instead, you should specify your own document and display format (or use an existing one), or use a library *(as ridoansaleh suggested)*.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought I'd share what ended up working.

First put all the notes on a text file, then create a scripts.js file with:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const data = fs.readFileSync('./notes.txt', 'utf-8');

const json = {
    data: data,
};

const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);

console.log(json);

fs.writeFileSync('./notes.json', jsonStr);
```

And this on the app.js file:

```
const notesJson = require('./notes.json');

function App() {

  return (
    <pre className="App">
      {notesJson.data}
    </pre>
  );
}

export default App;
```